# How to create equivalent view in cloudant for distinct and cout query in mysql

Tags: cloudant, nosql

I have 1000 documents of type below and I want to design a document in cloudant (write a view) equivalent to this Mysql query:

```
 (SELECT 
      COUNT(DISTINCT(correlationassetid)), PERIOD 
  FROM 
      view_asset 
  WHERE 
      ((PERIOD >= '201705') AND (PERIOD <= '201705')) 
  GROUP BY 
      PERIOD 
  ORDER BY 
      PERIOD ASC)
```

I have tried below view but it does not give proper result. could any one help me?

```
function (doc) {
  if(doc.type == "asset"){
    emit(doc.period,1);
  }

{
  "_id": "24dee0ec910e22605fe8fc4189000c56",
  "_rev": "1-d667f0b4ce3d984c0d7aafadd223674a",
  "parentName": "",
  "period": "201701",
  "providerGlobalAssetId": "",
  "cost": "5",
  "providerRegionCode": "",
  "owner": "",
  "snapshotId": "659c5f7a-35d62", 
  "correlationAssetId": "aws-6082634880291"
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [count number of rows in cloudant in response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44106569/count-number-of-rows-in-cloudant-in-response)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused by your example query and your sample document because there are some inconsistencies, but I am going to try to answer your question based on a couple assumptions.

If you are filtering by a single PERIOD value no GROUPBY clause should be required in your SQL statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(correlationassetid))
FROM view_asset 
WHERE PERIOD = '201705'
```

Defining the following design document

```
{
  "_id": "_design/howdoi",
  "views": {
    "filter-by": {
      "map": "function (doc) {\n  if(doc.type === \"asset\") {\n   emit([doc.period, doc.correlationAssetId], 1);\n  }\n}",
      "reduce": "_count"
    }
  },
 "language": "javascript"
}
```

a `GET` request to query the view

```
 https://$USER:$PASSWORD@$HOST/$DATABASE/_design/howdoi/_view/filter-by?inclusive_end=true&start_key=[%22201705%22]&end_key=[%22201705%22%2C{}]&reduce=true&group_level=2
```

should return the desired result if you specify `start_key=["201705"]` and `end_key=["201705",{}]`.

Example response if there are two documents within that period, both containing the same `correlationAssetId`:

```
 {
  "rows": [
   {
    "key": [
      "201705",
      "aws-6082634880291"
    ],
    "value": 2
  }
 ]
}
```

The number of rows in the result set should identify the distinct number of `correlationAssetId`s for the specified PERIOD.

Example result for two `correlationAssetId`s:

```
{
  "rows": [
    {
      "key": [
        "201701",
        "aws-6082634880291"
      ],
      "value": 1
    },
    {
     "key": [
       "201701",
       "aws-6082634880292"
     ],
     "value": 1
   }
  ]
 }
```

P.S. Your example document didn't define the `asset` property and your view definition would therefore not have returned the document. My response above assumes that that property is defined in the documents.

Comment: Thanks ptitzler. Yes i missed the type: asset in document(it was a long document and while making it short to paste here by mistake i removed type property.)

Comment: With your above solution, yes i am getting correct number of rows,(please bear with me i can ask some silly quetions as i am new to cloudant) is there any way to count and show the total number of rows in response. For example i am getting total rows as 1810 which is correct, but i want to see the response in somewhat below format...                         {"rows":[ {"key":["201705"],"value":1810} ]}

Comment: Now how can i count the number of rows and show in response something like  {"rows":[ {"key":["201705"],"value":1810} ]}